# Cannot invoke initializer for type: with an argument list of type:

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  When initializing an object, I can't seem to have an Array from another class as a parameter.  Here is my specific situation:

I am trying to create a workout app.  The app contains several different workouts.  Each workout has it's own unique array of drills.

I have my code for WorkoutObj (This struct creates a workout and needs an NSArray workoutDrillSet)

```
import UIKit

struct WorkoutObj {

var workoutType: NSString
var workoutNumber: Int
var workoutDesc: NSString
var workoutDuration: Int
var workoutDrillSet: NSArray

init(type: String, number: Int, duration: Int, desc: String, drillSet: NSArray)
{
    workoutType = type
    workoutNumber = number
    workoutDuration = duration
    workoutDesc = desc
    workoutDrillSet = drillSet
}

}
```

Here are my DrillObjects (This struct is the object that the drill array will be comprised of - in others words, the drill array will consist of DrillObject1, DrillObject2, DrillObject3, etc)

```
import UIKit

struct DrillObject {

var drillDesc: NSString
var drillDurationMin: Int
var drillDurationSec: Int
var drillHRZone: Int
var drillEffort: Int
var drillCadence: Int

init(M: Int, S: Int, hRZone: Int, effort: Int, cadence: Int, name: NSString)
{
    drillDesc = name
    drillDurationMin = M
    drillDurationSec = S
    drillHRZone = hRZone
    drillEffort = effort
    drillCadence = cadence
}

}
```

My next class is my EDrills Class.  This Class puts each DrillObject into an array.  The array created is called, arrayE1Drills

```
import UIKit

class EDrills: NSObject {

let dE1: DrillObject
let dE2: DrillObject
let dE3: DrillObject
let dE4: DrillObject
let dE5: DrillObject
let dE6: DrillObject
let dE7: DrillObject
let dE8: DrillObject
let dE9: DrillObject
let dE10: DrillObject
let dE11: DrillObject
let dE12: DrillObject
let dE13: DrillObject
let dE14: DrillObject

var arrayE1Drills : [DrillObject]


override init()
{
    dE1 = DrillObject ( M: 5, S: 0,  hRZone: 2, effort: 8, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Pedal Easy @ 90 RPM")

    dE2 = DrillObject ( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Stand")
    dE3 = DrillObject ( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Sit")

    dE4 = DrillObject ( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Stand")
    dE5 = DrillObject ( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Sit")

    dE6 = DrillObject ( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Stand")
    dE7 = DrillObject ( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Sit")

    dE8 = DrillObject ( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Stand")
    dE9 = DrillObject ( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Sit")

    dE10 = DrillObject( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Stand")
    dE11 = DrillObject( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Sit")

    dE12 = DrillObject( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Seated 80% left leg")
    dE13 = DrillObject( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Seated 80% right leg")

    dE14 = DrillObject( M: 0, S: 30, hRZone: 2, effort: 10, cadence: 95, name: "W/U Seated 80% left leg")


    arrayE1Drills =
    [dE1,
    dE2,
    dE3,
    dE4,
    dE5,
    dE6,
    dE7,
    dE8,
    dE9,
    dE10,
    dE11,
    dE12,
    dE13,
    dE14]


}

}
```

Finally, I have the Class EWorkouts.  This is a class that holds several workouts.  The e1 workoutObject needs to hold the arrayE1Drills of the EDrills class.

```
import UIKit


class EWorkouts {

var e1: WorkoutObj
var e2: WorkoutObj
var e3: WorkoutObj
var e4: WorkoutObj
var e5: WorkoutObj

var arrayEAll : [WorkoutObj]
var arrayE0to45 : [WorkoutObj]
var arrayE30to45: [WorkoutObj]
var arrayE45to60: [WorkoutObj]
var arrayEGreater45: [WorkoutObj]
var arrayE0to60: [WorkoutObj]
var arrayEGreater60: [WorkoutObj]

var myEDrillsClass : EDrills


 init()
{
    myEDrillsClass = EDrills()
    let myArray = myEDrillsClass.arrayE1Drills


    e1 = WorkoutObj(type: "E", number: 1, duration: 63, desc: "Rolling Hilly Course", drillSet: myArray)

 }
```

When Trying to load the arrayE1Drills into the workout, I get an error: `Cannot invoke initializer for type "WorkoutObjc" with an argument list of type (type: String, number: Int, duration: Int, desc: String, drillSet: [DrillObject])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are type mismatches

`var workoutType: NSString` --> `init : String`

`var workoutDesc: NSString` --> `init : String`

and later `NSArray` <--> `Array`

Since Swift 1.2 the Foundation basic types are not implicitly casted to the Swift counterparts

I recommend to use only the Swift types